# Can you paginate a nested query with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to paginate this nested query?

**User.php**

```
public function favoritePosts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'favoritable', 'favorites')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

**ProfilesController.php**

```
public function posts($username)
{
    $user = User::with(['profile', 'favoritePosts' => function($q){
        $q->paginate(15);
    }])->whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail();
    return view('profiles.posts')->withUser($user);
}
```

**profiles/posts.blade.php**

```
...
{!! $user->favoritePosts->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
...
```

**error**

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::appends()`

Comment: Pretty sure `paginate()` serves as results presenter, not as a query building method. What are you trying to achieve in the `posts()` method anyway?

Comment: @lesssugar Thanks for the comment. I needed to paginate the posts on the users profile page, it ended up being extremely straight forward to do. I added an answer if it helps anybody else.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using two queries.

```
public function posts($username)
{
    $user = User::with('profile')->whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail();
    $posts =  $user->favoritePosts()->paginate(15);
    return view('profiles.posts')->withUser($user)->with(compact('posts'));
}
```